# Passive mixed-content is blocked as if it was active mixed-content

Tags: html, mixed-content

The [Mozilla page about mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) specifies two types of mixed content: passive and active.

> Mixed passive/display content is content served over HTTP that is
> included in an HTTPS webpage, but that cannot alter other portions of
> the webpage.
>
> #### Passive content list
>
> This section lists all types of HTTP requests which are considered
> passive content:
>
> - < img > (src attribute)
> - < audio > (src attribute)
> - < video > (src attribute)
> - < object > subresources (when an  performs HTTP requests)

The [Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content) uses the same distinction, and specifies the kind of errors Chrome will display for each of those:

[image: Passive mixed-content]
*Passive mixed-content*

[image: Active mixed-content]
*Active mixed-content*

So the specs are pretty clear: active mixed content (scripts, css, etc.) is blocked and throws a big red error; passive mixed content (images, videos, etc.) is not blocked but throws nice and yellow warnings.

Then, why do I have this:

[image: Blocked passive mixed-content]

This comes from an < img > tag, and is clearly recognized by Chrome as an image - but it is blocked in the same way as active mixed content, with big red warnings and all.

How comes?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Ouroborus Would that I could :/ I have absolutely no idea what caused this issue, it comes from a *very* complex project, and I can't manage to reproduce it in simpler projects. That's why if anybody had a clue about what can cause a browser to block passive mixed content, that would be great

Comment: @Cristol.GdM were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Dryadwoods Yes... kind of. Getting the image from an https source worked, so I don't have the problem anymore. BUT I still don't know why a mixed-content image was blocked